# Let $s(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n\in\mathbb N$ that are squares. Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n s(i) < \frac{(\pi^2)}{6}$.

Tags: combinatorics

I believe I need to use the rule of double counting but I am struggling to find an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix a square. Lets say $d^2,$ then show that the number of multiples from $1$ to $n$ is $\lfloor \frac{n}{d^2}\rfloor<\frac{n}{d^2}.$ Use this to try to exchange the sum from being on $i$ to be on $d.$ What do you know about the sum $\sum _{d=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{d^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use double counting: $$\sum_{k=1}^n{s(k)}=\sum_{1 \leq d \leq n}{\sum_{a^2|d}{1}} = \sum_{a \geq 1}{\sum_{1 \leq d \leq n,a^2|d}{1}}=\sum_{1 \leq a \leq \sqrt{n}}{\sum_{k \geq 1,ka^2 \leq n}{1}} \leq \sum_{1 \leq a \leq \sqrt{n}}{\frac{n}{a^2}}\leq n\sum_{i=1}^n{i^{-2}} < n\zeta(2)=n\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Try proving that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n s(i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{i^2}\bigg\rfloor$$